# How to write JS Files with clearly representation?

Tags: javascript, code-formatting

The thing is that I have a very large JS file, with more than 5.000 lines of code, which holds several objects (some inherit from others), functions and so on.

but if you try to find something, you need much time, because it is so big and my IDE (Netbeans) does not really represent it clearly enough.
I.e. the navigation does not support JS very well, and merges variables with same names, although they are local vars and occure in different objects.

I don't really want to split it into many files (i.e. for each object one), because I have to merge them again on the live server.

how do you structure your JS files?
have you found a well naming scheme or something?

**UPDATE:**

So far I found, that splitting into many files is a good idea... How do you name your files? how do u organzie them?

Comment: Having to merge them on a live server or not, you should still be separating them. The combining and minification of your assets (HTML + CSS) should be built into your (automated) build/ release process and shouldn't be a limiting factor.

Comment: JSHint is a tool to detect errors and potential problems in JavaScript code.

Comment: Matt is right - large JS files should absolutely be split out to several files. This is a design choice that should be made from the start. It sounds like you need to do some research into methodologies and patterns. Try chapter 6 of Stoyan Stefanov's Javascript Patterns (O'Reilly).

Comment: @Matt Yep, I think I have to bit that bullet. But still, I have Objects with hundrets of lines...

Comment: @helle: If your objects are *many* hundreds, you should look at re-factoring them into smaller objects. I order my object methods/ members by constructor, public members and then private members.

Comment: ... I guess you can optionally order each of those sections alphabetically, but I've never had the need to be so stringent. Provided you have good documentation for each of those methods, you should be able to CTRL+F your methods and find them with any relevant search term. I've had a flick through a 8,000+ JS project and the largest files on there are ~500 lines (42 files across the project).

Comment: Thanks guys so far. Next question: how do you name your files? do you organize them in directories?

Comment: @helle: Each file should contain object(s) with a common theme; so call it something which represents that theme. Group your files into folders which have a more abstract theme, and call them that... keep going as far as necessary (but not too far! 2/3 levels deep should be enough).

Comment: @helle: It might be worthwhile to look at some [open source JavaScript projects](https://github.com/languages/JavaScript/most_watched) and see how they structure their code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My setup has separate files for each object. This is ideal for me because it makes finding things very easy.

It's also very easy to have a simple 'build' script that concatenates all the files together in the proper order. I also have my script run the concatenated file through the [Closure Compiler](http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/) which makes an unreadable mess, but compacts my scripts to about 1/3 the original size.

In my opinion, it's worth the minimal effort of making a 'build' script to have all the clarity of separate files.

**EDIT:**

Another benefit of this is that I have two versions of my script. The concatenated 'debug' version that is human-readable and the minified 'production' version that is definitely not.

When I'm trying things out, the page links the readable version; when it goes live, the page links the minified version for faster loading (and readability is no longer important).

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend splitting it into many smaller, maintainable files, and then using [SquishIt](https://github.com/jetheredge/SquishIt) (or the like, depending on your server side language) in production to minify and concatenate your scripts back to a single file.

Comment: Honest curiosity here, how is Nico's answer better than mine? Was mine too 'wall of text'? How can I improve?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I don't get lost in my .JS files is delimitating each and everysingle function/objects by 3 lines of comments like this :
/*-------------------------------------------------------*/
/*----------------SECTION BC-204----------------*/
/*-------------------------------------------------------*/

The other way I'd see is as you stated splitting them in different files but even there it would still be a pain to go through all of them.